# Advise in generating ESP surfaces from Gaussian .cube files using the IQmol software

Tags: molecular-modeling, gaussian, visualization-software, potential-energy-surface, q-chem

I am trying to generate an ESP surface of a Gaussian09 calculation using the iqmol software. I have used Gaussview to visualize the ESP surface by generating .cube files from .fchk files (using the cubgen utility), however, I prefer the visualization settings of iqmol (I do not have the time to play around with visualization settings with other softwares).

The iqmol software requires a .cube file to generate the ESP surface (the software manual outlines the process to generate the ESP once a .cube file is loaded), however, every time I load the .cube file (generated from the cubegen utility) into the iqmol software, I get an error stating that the software cannot parse the information.

I have limited experience with computational modeling (and frankly programming languages), however, I have seen from some of my research that each quantum chemistry program has different formats for .cube files. I assume the failure of iqmol to parse Gaussian09 .cube data is the result of incompatibility of the visualization software with the Gaussian .cube file. I have heard that there are ways of converting .cube file formats, however due to my lack of knowledge of programming (and time constraints), I would prefer to stray from this solution.

The .fchk file contains all the relevant data to generate the .cube file for the ESP surface using the Gaussian cubegen utility, however, when the .fchk file is imported into iqmol (they are compatible), I cannot find the options to generate anything regarding the ESP surface.

My question is:

Does anyone have experience visualizing ESP surfaces using .fchk/.cube files generated from Gaussian09 outputs using the iqmol software? Do I need to rerun the Gaussian09 single point calculations using certain keywords in the route section?

I appreciate all the suggestions/help (and I hope this makes sense). Thank you.